# Django modelform widget readonly render text not input field

Tags: html, django, modelform

I have a modelform with readonly fields that render as a HTML input widget with an ugly 'no-entry' mouseover image (firefox) when the text inside the input box is selected - default behaviour for 'models.TextField' fields to render as input I believe.

```
self.fields['project_path'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
self.fields['media_path'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
self.fields['responsible'] = SysEventChoiceField(User.objects.all().order_by('first_name'))
```

I want to render the modelform with a mixture of read only fields as pure text without the input boxes in the form. The result should look something like this in html..

```
<p>D:\This\Path</p>
<p>E:\This\other\path</p>
<input value="Bob Smith" name="user"></input>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can replace the `<input>` tag from Django Form. Instead you can get the fields you would like to display as `<p>` and display them individually.

in your views.py

```
# get the fields you want to display as <p>
my_field = form['my_field'].value()

# remove from the form 
delete form['my_field']

# pass the parameters to render in your template
return render_to_response('project.html', {
    'my_field': my_field,
    'form': form
})
```

in your template project.html

```
<p>{{my_field}}</p>
{{form}}
```

Alternatively, you can also do something like this:

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field.value }}
{% endfor %}
```

There is also the method [as_p()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates), but this will just wrap your input fields in a `<p>` tag which I don't think you want.

Comment: This is also what I am doing, but it feels like I'm missing something simple like  'self.fields['media_path'].widget.attrs['text_only'] = True